# Configuring an c++ OpenCV project with Cmake

Tags: opencv, cmake

I consider this a fundamental step for creating projects that use OpenCV libraries so you don't need to manually include all the libraries. There is not detailed information on this topic, at least for a newbie that just wants to use OpenCV as soon as posible, so:

**Which is the easiest and scalable way to create a multiplatform c++ OpenCV with Cmake?**

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**First:** create a folder **Project** containing two subfolders **src** and **include**, and a file called **CMakeLists.txt**.

**Second:** Put your cpp inside the src folder and your headers in the include folders.

**Third:** Your `CMakeLists.txt` should look like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8) 
PROJECT (name)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED )
set( NAME_SRC
    src/main.cpp    
)

set( NAME_HEADERS
    include/header.h
)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES( ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include )
link_directories( ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
add_executable( name ${NAME_SRC} ${NAME_HEADERS} )

target_link_libraries( sample_pcTest ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

**Fourth:** Open CMake GUI and select the root folder as input and create a build folder for the output. Click configure, then generate, and choose the generator (VisualStudio, Eclipse, ...)

Comment: Please don't recommend using "link_directories" -- instead, give the full path names to any libraries required as arguments to target_link_libraries. The docs for link_directories ( http://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command:link_directories ) say "Note that this command is rarely necessary."

Comment: You can omit the NAME_HEADERS -- CMake scans source files to determine header file dependencies.

Comment: @DLRdave In Windows you will need `link_directories(${OpenCV_LIB_DIR})` because the value returned in `${OpenCV_LIBS}` only include the library names (not the full path). If you want `${OpenCV_LIBS}` to actually include the library paths then you'll need `find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED core imgproc ...)`. When building statically that implies adding every single opencv module in the `find_package` call.

Comment: Interesting...... Thanks for the info, I did not realize that. It's against the norm, too, though. The OpenCV find_package call ought to return full path names to the libraries in the variable. The VAST majority of other find_package calls yield full path names to libraries.

Comment: Dlls not found configuring for Visual Studio

Comment: This answer is incomplete and does not work. It does not even reference the OpenCV include directories.

Answer (score 31):

I am using OpenCV 3.0 and CMake 3.8,
config below works for me!

```
######## A simple cmakelists.txt file for OpenCV() #############  
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)                            
PROJECT(word)                                         

FIND_PACKAGE( OpenCV REQUIRED )                              
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES( ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} )

ADD_EXECUTABLE(word main.c)                         
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES (word ${OpenCV_LIBS})         
########### end ####################################
```

Comment: apart from 'include_directories()' call is not required for  CMake >= 2.8.11 this is the only right way to go. And the self-accepted answer is totally misleading to say at least.