# Compilation of OpenCV using CMakeList under ROS

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, ros

I am trying to compile **openCV** code using **CmakeList.txt** (under **ROS** (Robot operating system)), my CmakeList is working, because on another PC it is working well. I installed OpenCV and in openCV examples directory I compiled examples using g++ and some flags, compilation was successful. But when I want to compile my other code using CmakeList, I get this **error**:

```
CMakeFiles/aupark_node.dir/src/wrapper.cpp.o: In function `Wrapper::set_head_image(std::string)':
wrapper.cpp:(.text+0x2ef1): undefined reference to `cv::imread(cv::String const&, int)'
```

in wrapper.cpp I had all appropriate includes.

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <image_transport/image_transport.h>
#include <cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/image_encodings.h>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
```

And my CMakeList.txt is here:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(aupark)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11 ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS cmake_modules roscpp gencpp moveit_ros_planning_interface moveit_msgs cv_bridge)
find_package(Eigen REQUIRED)
include_directories(${EIGEN_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_definitions(${EIGEN_DEFINITIONS})

catkin_package()

add_executable(aupark_node src/aupark_node.cpp src/wrapper.cpp src/wrapper.h)
target_link_libraries(aupark_node ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

What can be wrong?

output of pkg-config opencv --libs:

```
-L/usr/local/lib
-lopencv_shape 
-lopencv_stitching 
-lopencv_objdetect 
-lopencv_superres  
-lopencv_videostab 
-lopencv_calib3d 
-lopencv_features2d  
-lopencv_highgui 
-lopencv_videoio 
-lopencv_imgcodecs 
-lopencv_video 
-lopencv_photo 
-lopencv_ml 
-lopencv_imgproc 
-lopencv_flann 
-lopencv_viz 
-lopencv_core 
-lopencv_hal
```

Comment: I just found this [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13970377/configuring-an-c-opencv-project-with-cmake).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are not linking against OpenCV in your `CMakeLists.txt`.

To do so add `find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)` at the top and then link your target against it:

```
target_link_libraries(aupark_node ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

A minimal example on how to use OpenCV with cmake can be found in [the OpenCV documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_gcc_cmake/linux_gcc_cmake.html).

Comment: Thank you very much. It is working now. But it is interesting that on other PC I am able to compile it with the old CMakeList which doesn`t contain that lines which you suggested.

Comment: @wair92 Glad I could help. Yeah that made me wonder too when I read your question. To be honest, I have no idea what could be different on the other PC that makes it work there.