# How to import openCV with contrib on Android using CMake?

Tags: android, opencv, cmake, opencv-contrib

I try import openCV with contrib on Android. I referenced this site:

http://www.cnblogs.com/fx-blog/p/8206737.html

I failed to build opencv with contrib for Android, so I downloaded opencv with contrib sdk. I imported module, set dependency and write CMakeLists and build.gradle

Here is my CMakeLists and build.gradle

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
# For more information about using CMake with Android Studio, read the
# documentation: https://d.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html

# Sets the minimum version of CMake required to build the native library.

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

set(pathOPENCV E:/opencv/opencv3-android-sdk-with-contrib-master/OpenCV-android-sdk)
set(pathPROJECT C:/Users/sms28/Downloads/artoolkit-android-studio-example-    master/MyApplication7)
set(pathLIBOPENCV_JAVA C:/Users/sms28/Downloads/artoolkit-android-studio-example-    master/MyApplication7/app/src/main/JniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libopencv_java3.so)

set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE on)
# set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=gnu++11")

include_directories(${pathOPENCV}/sdk/native/jni/include)

# Creates and names a library, sets it as either STATIC
# or SHARED, and provides the relative paths to its source code.
# You can define multiple libraries, and CMake builds them for you.
# Gradle automatically packages shared libraries with your APK.    

add_library(libopencv_java3 SHARED IMPORTED )
set_target_properties(libopencv_java3 PROPERTIES
                      IMPORTED_LOCATION "${pathLIBOPENCV_JAVA}")


add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
             xfeatures2d

             # Sets the library as a shared library.
             SHARED

             # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
             src/main/cpp/xfeatures2d_init.cpp
             src/main/cpp/sift.cpp
             src/main/cpp/surf.cpp
             src/main/cpp/freak.cpp )

# Searches for a specified prebuilt library and stores the path as a
# variable. Because CMake includes system libraries in the search path by
# default, you only need to specify the name of the public NDK library
# you want to add. CMake verifies that the library exists before
# completing its build.

find_library( # Sets the name of the path variable.
              log-lib

              # Specifies the name of the NDK library that
              # you want CMake to locate.
              log )

# Specifies libraries CMake should link to your target library. You
# can link multiple libraries, such as libraries you define in this
# build script, prebuilt third-party libraries, or system libraries.

target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
                       xfeatures2d android log libopencv_java3

                       # Links the target library to the log library
                       # included in the NDK.
                       ${log-lib} )
```

**build.gradle (app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.sms28.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags "-std=c++11", "-frtti", "-fexceptions"
                abiFilters 'x86', 'x86_64','armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'
            }
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['src/main/jniLibs']
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
}    

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation project(':openCVLibrary340dev')
}
```

And I build it, but I got errors:

[click and show error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSHIv.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Here we expect error message to be in the question post as **text**, not linked as an image. Please, [edit] the question and insert textual representation of the error into it. You may format build log in the same way as a code. Also, it seems that instead of `CMakeLists.txt` content you have added your gradle script. Fix this issue too.

Comment: OMGI didnt notice that my Question was shit, I fix my Question :)

Comment: You still haven't fixed the error message being **as text**, not linked image... Anywhere, it is strange that you are trying to use OpenCV for 2 weeks, and don't google any example of that usage, e,g https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13970377/configuring-an-c-opencv-project-with-cmake.

Comment: i successed to use opencv on android. i just cant opencv with contrib ...