# How to correctly include a third party project stored on disk into my cmake project?

Tags: cmake

I have a project which uses cmake and would like to include opencv in it. I need this dependency to be used from my local disk at ./third_party/opencv. I have there the git repo contents https://github.com/opencv/opencv.

I'm new to CMake and not sure how to include this project within mine.

I've tried various things, most recently adding this to my CMakeLists.txt `include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/third_party/opencv)`. Which does not work. I get errors such as:

```
 undefined reference to `cv::rectangle(cv::Mat&, cv::Rect_<int>, cv::Scalar_<double> const&, int, int, int)
```

Here is my full CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)
project(root)

include(${CMAKE_ROOT}/Modules/ExternalProject.cmake)

FIND_PACKAGE(PkgConfig REQUIRED)

find_package(ZXing CONFIG)

# Locate GTest
find_package(GTest REQUIRED)
include_directories(${GTEST_INCLUDE_DIRS})

include_directories(
  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/third_party
)
include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/third_party/opencv)

add_executable(application ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/main.cpp)
add_executable(run_tests ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/tests/tests.cpp)
target_link_libraries(
  application
  ${GTEST_LIBRARIES} pthread ${ZBAR_LIBRARIES} ZXingCore
)
target_link_libraries(
  run_tests
  ${GTEST_LIBRARIES} pthread ${ZBAR_LIBRARIES} ZXingCore
)
```

Any idea of how I can do this correctly? Thanks

Comment: Did you try the CMake configurations described in the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13970377/configuring-an-c-opencv-project-with-cmake)?

Comment: That's answering a different question. I'm using opencv within my source tree

Comment: Did you try find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED PATHS third_party/opencv)

Comment: @BadrElHiouel that gives me this error https://pastebin.com/cnEDJP4j  with this cmakelists.txt contents https://pastebin.com/6EuSKvnn

Comment: Try this before find_package set("OpenCV_DIR" "/your/path/to/opencv/installation/dir")

Comment: Same error unfortunately @BadrElHiouel, here's my cmakelists again https://pastebin.com/shnRFTvw

Comment: the opencv github repo contains `cmake/templates/OpenCVConfig.cmake.in` but not `OpenCVConfig.cmake` . could that have something todo with it?

Comment: It seems that your opencv is not built/installed.