# How include openCV in VS Code

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

Since I don't have much experience, installing new C/C++ packages, this might be an obvious mistake. However, I found no solution for it yet.

The official tutorial for installing opencv is a bit unclear: https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html

I followed the steps as described under [Build with opencv_contrib](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html#tutorial_linux_install_quick_build_contrib). But I didn't follow the install steps since they sounded optional (h2). However, when I try to include `opencv` after building, opencv fails. How can I let VS Code know where to find my `opencv` build?

I am using the `C/C++`, `C/C++` Runner extensions if that helps answering my question.

Comment: My advice is not to use the code runner extension for this. You probably want to use the CMakeTools extension instead and write a `CMakeLists.txt` for your project.

Comment: This extension is called `CMake Tools`. Would you mind giving a more detailed explanation on how to write a `CMakeLists.txt` or point me towards the right direction?

Comment: There is an example in the documentation; [https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/db/df5/tutorial_linux_gcc_cmake.html](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/db/df5/tutorial_linux_gcc_cmake.html) although its a bit old and uses older CMake techniques. It still should work however. I will look for a better example.

Comment: Here is another old example: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13970377/configuring-an-c-opencv-project-with-cmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13970377/configuring-an-c-opencv-project-with-cmake)

Comment: After more research the current opencv does not use the namespace alias feature of CMake so the above links are good. This will be used in opencv5: [https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/13117](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/13117)

Answer (score 0):

0)Hello world opencv code

```
   #include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
    int main()
    {
        cv::Mat a = cv::imread("111.jpeg");
        cv::imshow("sdfsf", a);
        cv::waitKey(0);
        return 0;
    }
```

1. Press ctrl+shift+p and "edit_configuration" for creating c_cpp_properties.json file and adding into it include path

   "includePath": [
   "${workspaceFolder}/**",
   "/usr/local/include/opencv4"
   ],
2. Add into tasks.json in "args"

   ```
        "-I/usr/local/include/opencv4",
        "-L/usr/local/lib",
        "-l", "opencv_imgcodecs",
        "-l", "opencv_core",
        "-l", "opencv_videoio",
        "-l", "opencv_imgproc",
        "-l", "opencv_highgui",
        "-l", "pthread"
   ```
3. compile and run
4. if you get " undefined symbol: __libc_pthread_init, version GLIBC_PRIVATE"
   error - run in Visual Studio terminal    "unset GTK_PATH"